# How to display products from z to a in a liquid template in Shopify

Tags: list, shopify, product, liquid

how to list the products in reverse order (i.e. from Z to A) in a liquid template?

Thanks for your help !

Here is my code but it doesn't work:

```
{% assign myproducts = collections.all.products | sort='title' | reverse %}
{% paginate myproducts by 1000 %}
  {% for product in myproducts %}
     {% include 'product-thumb' with size:'oneThird', thumbSize:'thirds' %} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: Try like this `collections.all.products | sort_natural | reverse`

Answer (score 0):

There are few syntax error in your code, but the main problem is that the pagination will not work (and there is no way to make it work).

```
{% assign myproducts = collections.all.products | sort: 'title' | reverse  %}

{% for product in myproducts %}
    {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will display the product in reverse order but without pagination.

Pagination doesn't work with assigned variables but only with collections.
You could write something like this

```
{% paginate collections.all.products by 3 %}
    {% for product in collections.all.products %}
        {{ product.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

But that's not reversed. And you can't reverse the collection before paginating. (You can reverse the single page, but that's not very useful).

**A solution is** to create your own manual collection, with the order you prefer (you set it on the shopify backend) and display that paginated.

To do that:

Go to your-shop .myshopify.com/admin/collections -> Create Collection -> You set a title -> You set a condition (could be price >0) -> Save. You can now sort it by title z-a.

Then in your code you can put

```
{% assign myproducts = collections['your-title'].products  %}

{% for product in myproducts %}
    {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine two or three product collections? Because here I can only list products from the same collection.

Comment: @Ravo it's easier if you create a collection that contains all the product you need.